# Sprintf MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to pass a matrix variable from MATLAB to python, but I am only acquiring the first element of that matrix in python. Does anyone know can get the full matrix?

Python

```
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = sys.argv[1]
    print x
```

MATLAB

```
A = magic(5);
[str,err] = sprintf('/usr/local/python name_of_program.py %d ', A);
unix(str)
```

Comment: if you change the line x = sys.argv[1] to sys.argv, what is the output?

Comment: I get the following:
['sqd.py', '16', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '5', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '9', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '4', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '2', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '11', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '7', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '14', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '3', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '10', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '6', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '15', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '13', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '8', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '12', '/usr/bin/python2.6', 'sqd.py', '1']

Answer (score 1):

Look at the contents of str:   `/usr/local/python name_of_program.py 17 /usr/local/python name_of_program.py 23 /usr/local/python name_of_program.py 4 ...`

When you pass a 5x5 matrix to sprintf, it reproduce the formatting string 25 times, with one of the elements substituted for the %d, in order (column by column).

I suggest another way to transfer data between the programs, such as writing it to a file.
If you really want to pass everything on the command line, try the following:

```
A_str = sprintf(' %d',A);
str = strcat('/usr/local/python name_of_program.py ',A_str);
```

Comment: Thanks, but with it, it seems to concatenating the name of file and the first element even with a space.  I got the following
   ??? Error using ==> python at 69
System error: /usr/bin/python: can't open file 'sqd.py16': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Command executed:

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use numpy to reshape the array, too.  Or if it's too much to import, you could make your own reshape function  Try this:

```
import sys, numpy
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = sys.argv[1::3]
    y = numpy.reshape(x, (5,5))
    print y
```

I also notice that the call is adding the string once for each element of A, so you might consider using [mat2str(A)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html), like:

```
[str, err] = sprintf('/usr/local/python program.py "%s" ', mat2str(A));
```

I've also changed the %d to %s, because you're passing it as a string on the python anyway.  The output of this is:

```
python program.py "[17 24 1 8 15;23 5 7 14 16;4 6 13 20 22;10 12 19 21 3;11 18 25 2 9]"
```

You can make a matrix from that string with numpy as well

```
>>> import sys
>>> import numpy

>>> print(numpy.matrix(sys.argv[1]))

matrix([[17, 24,  1,  8, 15],
    [23,  5,  7, 14, 16],
    [ 4,  6, 13, 20, 22],
    [10, 12, 19, 21,  3],
    [11, 18, 25,  2,  9]])
```

Comment: Thanks, but, how could it be adopted for uneven dimensions? (4x6)

Comment: The reshape function could be called like y = numpy.reshape(x, (4,4)).  The data is passed to argv without any shape information, so you either need to know what shape you're taking in, or pass that along as an argument as well.

Comment: Thank you, but if I had an uneven dimensions, how would that effect the sys.arvg[1::3]? I understand the reshape statement.

Comment: Uneven dimensions wouldn't affect that line.  The 1 is the position of the first matrix element and the 3 says to use every 3rd element.  By your output, it looks like that will cover all cases, because the matrix elements are every 3rd element of argv.  The double colon means to keep selecting elements until the end.

Comment: It seems that for uneven dimensions, there are extra elements in the set.

MATLAB
 0.1564    
    0.8555    
    0.6448   
    0.3763     
python
[['1.564050e-01' '8.555228e-01' '6.447645e-01' '3.762722e-01'
  '1.909237e-01' '4.282530e-01']
 The '1.909237e-01' '4.282530e-01' are added?

Comment: Where are the extra numbers coming from?  Can you show the matlab output, python output and sys.argv before it's reshaped?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20653/discussion-between-usmcs-and-carnez-davis)